# JSON.NET deserialize function does not return values

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I used JSON.NET DeserializeObject function and I'm not getting any value. All it returns is NULL! Help!

Here is the code (very simple code actually!):

```
public class FMKey
{
    public string keyName { get; set; }
    public string keyValue { get; set; }
}
public partial class GetFMDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FMID = "{\"id\":\"22\"}";
        var FM = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FMKey>(FMID);

        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        Response.Write("Received: " + FM.keyName + " " + FM.keyValue);
    }
}
```

Both FM.keyName and FM.keyValue contain NULL! What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your JSON does not match the properties in your class.

Comment: You have `id` in json and it doesn't match your properties of FMKey class..

Comment: So, what should it be? Thanks

Comment: `string FMID = "{\"keyName\":\"id\",\"keyValue\":\"22\"}";`

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON needs to match the definition of your class.  You'll want something like:

```
string FMID = "{\"keyName\":\"id\",\"keyValue\":\"22\"}";
var FM = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FMKey>(FMID);
```

One way to figure out the correct JSON is to build an object, then serialize it.

```
var test = new FMKey() {keyName = "id", keyValue = "22"};
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test); // This will spit out the correct JSON
```

Answer (score 1):

The json you're trying to deserialize does not match the definition of the object you're attempting to deserialize it into. If your object had only a single field - `id` of type string then it would work.

In order to deserialize with the generic method you need to provide an object with fields that all of the json properties can map to. Since you have no `id` field on your object it fails. If you use the general deserialize method you'll find it creates an anonymous object with a property of type string called `id`.